# Getting ChildObjects Listview - Appium

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, appium

I'm having a hard time getting the childobjects of a listview. So, there are multiple objects in it, visible and not yet visible. When I ask for the size, it returns 5 (those 5 are the visible ones).
I tried to scroll the list view from the bottom item to the top item and store those items but than I face the issue that items from other parts in the listview are recognized. Another method that I tried is to scroll the last item a little bit up, until the new item becomes visible. But here I face the issue that a whole other items text is recognized when the item is scrolled.

The code for the first method:
Within this code, I take the listviews childObjects, iterate through them and store all the textfields. When I do this, some textfields of other items are mixed which makes it unusable.

```
List AccountList;

ArrayList<String> AccountArray = new ArrayList<String>();
String tempAccountInfo = "";
String AccountType="";
String LastItem = "";
String NewLastItem = "N/A";
List<WebElement> AccountListItems;

AccountList = driver.findElements(getObject("ElementsWithinAccountListView"));
AccountListItems = AccountList.get(AccountList.size() - 1).findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));

while (!NewLastItem.equals(LastItem)) {
    for (int i=0; i<AccountList.size();i++){
        AccountList = driver.findElements(getObject("ElementsWithinAccountListView"));
        AccountListItems = AccountList.get(i).findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));
        switch (AccountList.get(i).getAttribute("className")){
            case "android.widget.LinearLayout":

                    if (!AccountListItems.get(0).getText().contains("New ")){
                        switch(AccountListItems.get(0).getText()){
                        case "Current accounts":
                            AccountType = "Current accounts";
                            break;
                        case "Savings accounts":
                            AccountType = "Saving accounts";
                            break;
                        case "Investments":
                            AccountType = "Investments";
                            break;
                        case "Credit cards":
                            AccountType = "Credit cards";
                            break;
                        case "Other":
                            AccountType = "Other";
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                break;
            case "android.widget.RelativeLayout":
                AccountListItems = AccountList.get(i).findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));
                if (AccountListItems.size() == 5 || AccountListItems.size() == 4){
                    tempAccountInfo = AccountType;
                    for(int j=0; j<AccountListItems.size(); j++){

                        tempAccountInfo = tempAccountInfo + "|" + AccountListItems.get(j).getText();
                        LastItem = AccountListItems.get(2).getText();

                    }

                    switch(AccountType){
                    case "Investments":
                        if (!(AccountListItems.size() == 5)) { 
                            System.out.println(tempAccountInfo);
                            AccountArray.add(tempAccountInfo);
                        }
                        break;
                    default: 
                        System.out.println(tempAccountInfo);
                        AccountArray.add(tempAccountInfo);
                        break;
                    }
                    tempAccountInfo = "";
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    driver.swipe(AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getLocation().x + 70, AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getLocation().y, AccountList.get(1).getLocation().x + 70, AccountList.get(1).getLocation().y, 3000);
    Thread.sleep(20000);

    AccountListItems = AccountList.get(AccountList.size() - 1).findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));
    try {
        NewLastItem = AccountListItems.get(2).getText();
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Not at the end of the listview");
        NewLastItem = "N/A";
    }
    System.out.println("LastItem:" + LastItem);
    System.out.println("NewLastItem:" + NewLastItem);
}
```

[Objects viewed in Appium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rybCS.png)

This is the code of the second method that I've tried:

```
protected void swipeToNextElement(String Element) throws Exception{
```

List AccountList;

```
String LastItem;
String NewLastItem;
List<WebElement> AccountListItems;
Boolean loop = true;


AccountList = driver.findElements(getObject(Element));
AccountListItems = AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));

LastItem = AccountListItems.get(0).getAttribute("text");
NewLastItem = AccountListItems.get(0).getAttribute("text");
driver.swipe(AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getLocation().x + (AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getSize().width / 2), AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getLocation().y, AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getLocation().x + (AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getSize().width / 2), AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getLocation().y - 70, 1000);

while (loop) {


    if (NewLastItem.equals(LastItem)){
        AccountList = driver.findElements(getObject(Element));
        AccountListItems = AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));
        driver.swipe(AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getLocation().x + (AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getSize().width / 2), AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getLocation().y, AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getLocation().x + (AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getSize().width / 2), AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getLocation().y - 70, 1000);
        NewLastItem = AccountListItems.get(0).getAttribute("text");
    } else {
        AccountList = driver.findElements(getObject(Element));
        AccountListItems = AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));
        driver.swipe(AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getLocation().x + (AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getSize().width / 2), AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getLocation().y, AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getLocation().x + (AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getSize().width / 2), AccountList.get(AccountList.size()-1).getLocation().y + 70, 1000);
        NewLastItem = AccountListItems.get(0).getAttribute("text");
        loop = false;
    }
}

System.out.println("NewLastItem: " + NewLastItem);
```

}

Any help is welcome ^^

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's painful when you try to get the items from a long list on Android.
And it's hard to get the complete list if some items are invisible and even harder when some of them are the same to Appium. 
So my suggestion is to avoid testing a long list.

Comment: Yes, but we really need it :)

Comment: I would suggest once you implement a generic code to handle different list views - please share it on github. I will help a lot pf people. :)